# Remove the "required " text appearing below textfields

Tags: model-view-controller, view, playframework-2.2

i have created a form in playframework but its showing **required** text below the text boxes which i have specified required in my model.
My problem is that i want to remove the **required** text that is appearing below the fields

my code

```
@main(title,nav="add") {


<fieldset>
    <legend><h2>Add</h2></legend>



@form(action = routes.ShopController.submit(),'name ->"userForm", 'id -> "shopCreationForm", 'class -> "form-horizontal", 'role->"form", 'onsubmit -> "return validateForm(this);") {

@inputText(userForm("name"), '_label -> "Shop Name*",'class -> "form-control")
@inputText(userForm("addressLine1"), '_label -> "Address Line 1*",'class -> "form-control")
@inputText(userForm("addressLine2"), '_label -> "Address Line 2",'class -> "form-control")
@inputText(userForm("addressLine3"), '_label -> "Address Line 3",'class -> "form-control")
@inputText(userForm("city"), '_label -> "City*",'class -> "form-control")
@inputText(userForm("town"), '_label -> "Town*",'class -> "form-control")
@inputText(userForm("phoneNumber"), '_label -> "Phone*",'class -> "form-control")



    <div>
        <label >Owner Email</label>
        <input type="email" name="owner.email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" value="@user" placeholder="@user" readonly>
    </div>

</fieldset>

    <div class="actions">
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Create">
        <a href="@routes.ApplicationController.index" class="btn">Cancel</a>
    </div>

  }




        }
        }
```

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Add an attribute `'_showConstraints->false`

like

```
@inputText(userForm("name"), '_label -> "Shop Name*", '_showConstraints->false, 'class -> "form-control")
```